# Do periods and question marks come inside the quotation mark, or outside?

Tags: punctuation, question-marks, quotation-marks, periods

I am very well aware of punctuation usage difference between American and British usage, but this part confuses me a little.

Example:

> A. Why did he ask, "Who are you?"
>   B. Why did he ask, "Who are you?"?
>   C. Why did he ask, "Who are you"?

The reason I am confused is because a question is enclosed in a question.
Now I know when to put a question mark inside and outside quotation mark:

> He asked, "Will you go and jump in the pond?" [a question within a statement]
>
> He really said, "Go jump in the pond"? [a statement within a question]

So, which one of the three options is correct? Same goes for use of the period. Should it be placed inside or outside:

> D. He said, "Pluck that flower."
>   E. He said, "Pluck that flower".
>   F. He said, "Pluck that flower.".

If I pick the D option, would it also mean that my sentence ended with the enclosed sentence?
If I pick the E option, would it mean that my sentence ended while the enclosed sentence was incomplete?

B. and F. seems awkward. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following rule is used in both American English, and in British English:

> If a "wrapping sentence" ends with a quotation,
>   and if the quotation ends with the same punctuation mark as the wrapper,
>   then include the punctuation mark within the quotation,
>   and omit the duplicate punctuation mark outside the quotation.
>
> I said, "No."
>   Do your kids always ask "Why?"
>   Jack yelled, "Jill!"

As a computer programmer, I have learned to fastidiously avoid inserting incorrect punctuation into quotations.  I would rather shorten a quotation (to omit a conflicting final punctuation mark) than change the punctuation mark at the end of the quotation.  My practice conflicts with what most American English teachers teach.

> If the wrapping sentence ends with a quotation,
>   and if the quotation ends with a different punctuation mark than the wrapper,
>   then omit the punctuation mark within the quotation,
>   and include the wrapper's punctuation mark outside the quotation.
>   For example, if I were to quote the previous three quotations:
>
> Did I say "No"?
>   That's the fifth time your kid has asked "Why"!
>   Jack said something about "Jill".

Of the choices in the original question, I would prefer (A) and (D).

There are situations where I might use (C) and (E).  For example, if the quotations are actually parts of longer sentences that continue past the quotations, then I would prefer (C) and (E).

Comment: For the record, where a quotation goes in relation to a period is a matter of style. AP style always puts the quote outside the period. Oxford style puts it as you have it here.

Comment: Agreed. This feels `“wrong,”` for the same reason this *is* `<i>wrong<i>/` Encapsulation should follow logic.